Proyecto en React Native, con expo, no obtengo funciona el expoPushToken en el apk
Hice un apk en expo con eas, cuando trato de usar las notificaciones en el apk no genera el expoPushToken, no lo obtiene. Me funciona en el expo pero no en el apk.
